# module 'aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb' has no attribute 'TableEncryption'

Tags: python-3.8, aws-cdk

I'm following the aws cdk [workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com/30-python/70-advanced-topics/100-construct-testing/1000-assertion-test.html)

The last `pytest` from the advanced [topics](https://cdkworkshop.com/30-python/70-advanced-topics/100-construct-testing/1000-assertion-test.html)
throws:

`AttributeError: module 'aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb' has no attribute 'TableEncryption'`

What did I miss?

```
self._table = ddb.Table(
    self, 'Hits',
    partition_key={'name': 'path', 'type': ddb.AttributeType.STRING},
    encryption=ddb.TableEncryption.AWS_MANAGED,
)
```

.

```
pip3 freeze | grep dynamodb

aws-cdk.aws-dynamodb==1.23.0
```

Answer (score 1):

CDK version 1.23.0 didn't have [TableEncryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.TableEncryption.html).

It's there in the [latest version](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1.134.0/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb/lib/table.ts) (1.134.0 as of today). It wasn't there in [1.23.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1.23.0/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb/lib/table.ts).

Based on the [blame log](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blame/v1.134.0/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb/lib/table.ts#L96) it was added with https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/7425. Based on the [changelog](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) this PR was merged in for version 1.39.0.

You are on a very old version of CDK. It's a year and a half old. You should upgrade.

Comment: @jjk This answer is better than mine.  I misread your locked CDK version as 1.123, not the ancient 1.23.